# My Sturmey-Archer gears seem to 'slip' - why?

Tags: sturmey-archer

This is not really a problem as such - but I am curious.

I have a Pashley bike with a Sturmey-Archer, internal, 3-speed gear, which I have recently cleaned and repaired (changed a broken pawl). And now, since I've just worked on it, I'm perhaps more alert to how it works - it's got its click back, and the gear changes are really slick; the only thing I wonder about is, if I eg start in the lowest gear, then shift up to the middle and then the highest gear, it feels like it slips a tiny bit ('settles'?) in the high gear before it engages. And then if I go down to the low gear, the same thing happens. There doesn't seem to be any problem connected to this, and I remember this from the past, now that I'm thinking about it, so I have lived with it for a long time.

It is hard to look inside the hub as it runs, so I have no idea what is happening. Any ideas what this may be?